# How to use C++ std::barrier arrival_token?

Tags: c++, barrier

I keep getting a compiler error when using the `std::barrier` `arrive` and `wait` functions separately.

I've been trying to find examples of using these functions but I can't find them so I'm just shooting wild at this point.

It complaines that my arrival token is not an rvalue, so I changed the declaration to use `&&`, but I'm not that familiar with how rvalues work.

Here's the code:

```
void thread_fn(std::barrier<>& sync_point)
{
    /* Do 1st task... */

    std::barrier<>::arrival_token&& arrival = sync_point.arrive();

    /* Do 2nd task... */

    /* Wait for everyone to finish 1st task */
    sync_point.wait(arrival);

    /* Do 3rd task... */
}
```

I get the compile error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void thread_fn(std::barrier<>&)’:
test.cpp:12:21: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘std::barrier<>::arrival_token&&’ to lvalue of type ‘std::barrier<>::arrival_token’
   12 |     sync_point.wait(arrival);
      |                     ^~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable with an rvalue reference type is an lvalue (`arrival` is an lvalue).

[`std::barrier<>::wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/barrier/wait) takes an `arrival_token&&`, so you need to move from the lvalue:

```cpp
sync_point.wait(std::move(arrival));
```